# Fresh Handlebars install produces ReferenceError on first run

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use Handlebars, and getting an indefatigable error. Tried both local install and global install.

```
$ sudo npm install -g handlebars
$ handlebars
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/handlebars/lib/handlebars/base.js:8
Handlebars.VERSION = "1.0.beta.5";
^
ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/handlebars/lib/handlebars/base.js:8:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/handlebars/lib/handlebars/base.js:100:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
    at require (module.js:375:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/handlebars/lib/handlebars.js:1:80)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
```

Some other useful information:

```
$ node --version
v0.6.19
$ npm --version
1.1.24
```

I also attempted to edit the file handlebars/base.js. I changed the top line to read

```
Handlebars = this.Handlebars = {}
```

which temporarily eliminated the first error I was receiving. But then a subsequent error popped up:

```
$ handlebars
module.js:337
    throw new Error("Cannot find module '" + request + "'");
          ^
Error: Cannot find module './parser'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:337:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
    at require (module.js:375:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/handlebars/lib/handlebars/compiler/base.js:1:80)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
```

Does anyone else have problems installing Handlebars, or have advice on how to get an installation up and running?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use the command line handlebars or trying to import the module handlebars?

The first will require you to use the -g argument when installing package. The latter will require you to install handlebars without the -g argument. The -g argument is only used for packages that create commands/programs in your shell.

So if you are compiling some files with the command line you do:

```
npm install -g handlebars
```

Shell

```
$ handlebars # should output all the command line options.
```

If you want to use it in one of your modules you do:

```
npm install handlebars
```

file.js

```
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');
console.log(handlebars); // should output all the methods.
```

Comment: I'm trying to gain access to the command line tool. As I mentioned, I tried with the `-g` option and experienced the error mentioned here.

Comment: What happens when you don't use sudo?

Comment: I tried that as well. `npm install handlebars`, `cd handlebars/bin`, `./handlebars` produces the exact same error.

Comment: What happens if you try something else. For example `npm install -g coffeescript` Then try `coffee`

Comment: Good question. `sudo npm install -g coffee-script`, then `coffee` and I see the Coffeescript terminal. Seems to work great.

Comment: @pickels, I get this error trying to build the Handlebars.js file, rather than including it